# Taking multiple search queries at a time for mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am facing issue I need to take multiple search query at a time in a url for backend purpose
like `{{serverAddress}}/v1/videos?genres=Education,Sports` serveraddress represent the ip address but in my backend code I can only take one parameter but need to take one or two parameters and the output should Return videos belonging to “Education” or “Sports” genre and videos are the mongoose collection but it is throwing error ""value" must be one of [Education, Sports, Movies, Comedy, Lifestyle, All]",
My backend code

./validation.js

```
const queries ={
  query:Joi.object().keys({
    sortBy: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('viewCount', 'releaseDate')).single(),
    genres: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('Education', 'Sports', 'Movies', 'Comedy', 'Lifestyle', 'All')).single(),
    contentRating:  Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('Anyone', '7+', '12+', '16+', '18+', 'All')).single(),

  }),
```

./route.js

```
router.get(
  "",
  validate(videoValidation.queries),
  videoController.genrequery,
);
```

I just know that the issue is with validate otherwise it won't throw the error and continue with next function which is videoController.genrequery

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the single function from the genres validator

Comment: Okay let me try that also

Comment: I removed single function it is saying  "\"genres\" must be an array", in validate function how can we store our search queries as an array

Comment: Get the values for genres as an array from the query parameters.
`{{serverAddress}}/v1/videos?genres=[Education,Sports]`
It will pass the validator.
Then, in the controller, parse the query param genres into JSON before using it in your database query.